# React Slick slider map not working not showing slides?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing the following problem, where the React Slick slider is not displaying my slides inside the map function. Tried multiple things, but keep getting empty values.

When i hardcode divs it works, but when i try to create them dynamic even when the exist the don't show up.

Can someone help?

```
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';
import GameCardDark from './GameCardDark';

const CardSlider = ({ asset, data }) => {

    function getSlides() {
        return data.map((slideData) => {
            console.log(slideData);
                <div className='card__slider_list'>
                    <GameCardDark key={slideData.id} asset={asset} data={slideData} />
                </div>
            })
    }

    const settings = {
        className: "center",
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: "0px",
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        speed: 400,
        rows: 1,
        swipeToSlide: true,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        dots: false,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 700,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    infinite: true,
                    dots: false,
                    centerPadding: "0px"
                }
            },
        ],
    };

    const slides = getSlides();
  

    return (
        <Slider {...settings}>
            <div className='card__slider_list'>
                {slides}
            </div>
        </Slider>
    )
}

export default CardSlider;
```

My slider not working in maping